# Question on dynamic allocation in vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, struct, stl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "malloc.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Write C++ code here
    vector<vector<vector<int*>>> storage;
    for (int i=0; i< 13; i++)
    {
        storage.push_back(vector<vector<int*>>()); 
        for (int j=0; j< 13; j++)
        {
            storage[i].push_back(vector<int*>());

            storage[i][j].push_back((int*)malloc(5 * sizeof(int)));
               
            for (int k =0; k<4; k++)
            {
                storage[i][j][k]=k;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to dynamically allocate a list inside the innermost dimension of the last vector, but it turns out it throws some compilation error when I try to set a value to the vector:

> error: invalid conversion from 'int' to '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<int*>, int*>::value_type' {aka 'int*'} [-fpermissive]

Comment: If you are asking what the error message means, please paste the full message into your question.  I suspect that your error has something to do with the difference between `int` and `int*`.

Comment: *I am trying to dynamically allocate a list inside the innermost dimension of the last vector* Don't, just use another vector and let it handle the memory management for you.

Comment: Whenever you feel the need to use a C-style cast (like you do with `(int*)malloc(...)`) you should take that as a sign that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Do you want a 3D or a 4D array? If you want 4D, you have too few nested loops and too few levels of `[]`. If you want 3D, you have one layer of arrays too many. (In this case I recommend removing `*` and `malloc`. By the way `malloc.h` is a wrong header, you need `stdlib.h`) The fact that you have `storage[i]` and `storage[i][j]` at the same indentation level right next to each other is a hint that something fishy is going on.

Comment: As for your problem it seems like you really want a vector of vector of pointers, i.e. `vector<vector<int*>>`. At least that's how you use `storage.

Comment: I want a 3D array. I was not in favor of using malloc. I was directed to use malloc. Not sure why. I personally feel using malloc does not make much sense here, but there was some force on me to use it, haha.

Comment: And using vectors all the way, you don't need any loops at all to create the vectors, it can all be done in the definition of the variable: `vector<vector<vector<int>>> storage(13, vector<vector<int>>(13, vector<int>(5)));` Then all you need is a loop to initialize the values of the innermost vector.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. What they would want is `<cstdlib>`, not stdlib.h.

Comment: As for the initialization I would use [range-based loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) and [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) instead: `for (auto& v1 : storage) { for (auto& v2 : v1) { std::iota(begin(v2), end(v2), 0); } }`

Comment: @sweenish Then they need to use `std::malloc` rather than `malloc`.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full and complete assignment, including any and all requirements and limitations.

Comment: It seems rather unusual that you are permitted to use `std::vector` for most of your object's dimensions, but are required to use the very C++ unfriendly `malloc` for exactly one of the dimensions.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. No. Also, they shouldn't use `malloc` at all.

Comment: A `vector<vector<vector<int*>>>`  is (one possible representation of) a 3D array *of pointers*.      If you want a 3D array of `int`, then consider using `vector<vector<vector<int>>>`.    Either way, using `malloc()` is a really BAD idea in your case -  if a teacher directed you to do this, particularly in C++, you need to find another teacher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you are trying to assign an `int` to an `int*`.  Specifically, on this statement:

```cpp
storage[i][j][k]=k;
```

`storage[i][j][k]` returns (a reference to) an `int*`, but `k` is an `int`.

Since you have 3 levels of vectors containing an `int[]` array, you need 4 loops to initialize the individual `int`s, but you only have 3 loops, so add another loop:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<vector<vector<int*>>> storage;
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; ++i)
    {
        storage.push_back(vector<vector<int*>>()); 

        for (int j = 0; j < 13; ++j)
        {
            storage[i].push_back(vector<int*>());

            for(int k = 0; k < N; ++k) // <-- decide what N should be!
            {
                storage[i][j].push_back(new int[5]);
               
                for (int m = 0; m < 5; ++m)
                {
                    storage[i][j][k][m] = k;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    // don't forget to delete[] all of the new[]'ed arrays!
    // consider using either std::unique_ptr<int[]> or
    // std::array<int,5> instead of int* ...

    return 0;
}
```

I would suggest simplifying the code to make it more readable, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

using arr5Ints = array<int, 5>;
using vec1D_arr5Ints = vector<arr5Ints>;
using vec2D_arr5Ints = vector<vec1D_arr5Ints>;
using vec3D_arr5Ints = vector<vec2D_arr5Ints>;

int main() {
    vec3D_arr5Ints storage(
        13,
        vec2D_arr5Ints(
            13,
            vec1D_arr5Ints(N) // <-- decide what N should be!
        )
    );

    for (auto &vec2d : storage)
    {
        for (auto &vec1d : vec2d)
        {
            for(auto &arr : vec1d)
            {
                int k = 0;
                for (int &i : arr)
                {
                    i = k++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're trying to index into the C-style array, in which case you would have to cut out one dimension of the vector, like so:

```cpp
vector<vector<int*>> storage;
```

Then you can index into the C-style array as expected.

`storage[i][j]` currently accesses a `vector` of `int*`, in which you have only pushed one element. If you want to keep the rest of your code the same you could just do `storage[i][j][0][k]=k`, however, I would advise removing a dimension instead.

Comment: Thanks. But in the code I pasted, doing this gives a segmentation fault. Looks like I'm missing something else too.

Comment: I've corrected my answer! ^^